# No programming just shortcut URL conversion

Tags: excel, url

Please just give me the Excel-shortcut for converting a long column of text URLs so that I don't have to go into each cell and do it.

I could not comment on a previous answer because I don't "qualify" so hence this repeated question.

This solution does not work because when I copy it down it does not change the reference cell from F2 to F3, F4, etc.
"... create new column alongside yoru column of URLs.  In the n ew column type in the formula =HYPERLILNK(A1) (replacing A1 with whatever cell you are interested in).  Then copy the formula down the rest of the 200 entries."

Copying this formula repeats the original formula (A1) all the way down so now I have a 200 plus list of the same URL.

How to activate all the different URLs to change to live URLs using that formula?  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Newbie

Comment: Use `=HYPERLINK(A1)`, **not**  `=HYPERLINK(A$1)` or  `=HYPERLINK($A$1)`. (note hyperLINK and not hyperLILNK).

Answer (score 0):

Just make *two entries* of that formula and THEN copy it all the way down.

If you do one cell then Excel "thinks" you want to simply REPEAT the formula exactly. If you do two (A1, B1) and then copy down it will "realise" that this is a "series" amnd then expand upon the series. It's easy to do, hard to explain! haha

Here's an example:

```
Foo 1
Bar 
Car
Do
```

If you highlight the "1" here and double click the bottom right hand corner the result will be:

```
Foo 1
Bar 1
Car 1
Do  1
```

However this:

```
Foo 1
Bar 2
Car 
Do
```

you highlight the 1 and 2, double cliock the bottom right hand corner and you will get:

```
Foo 1
Bar 2
Car 3
Do  4
```

Phew! :)